# nginx add cookies with parameters from servers

Tags: caching, cookies, nginx

I have something a bit complicated to check with you.

Let's having this url in my website.

/iframe/4444-2222-3333

I want nginx to put in cookies, the id of the iframe on the client side, and to be sure that the iframe all content will be entirely cached by my nginx server.

I will have something like this in my nginx location

```
location ~ /iframe/(?<varz>[^/]+)  {
 add_header iframeid $myvar;
 set $mobile_cookie  "mobile=$myvar;Path=/;Max-Age=1800";
}
```

each Id of iframe, can have a diffrente expiration date.

Is it possible to tell nginx to take the max-age from the cached request of each of the ids ?

Any idea ?

Thanks